# Eclipse creating .gitignore file and Open Resource not working

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jar, ear

I temporarily moved one folder in the source directory to another location, and in later commit restored it back to it's original place.

Now, the problem is Eclipse doesn't seem to handle this folder as it should anymore. First of all, searching for a resource contained in this folder using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work. It just doesn't find the resource. However, the folder is defined as source folder in the project settings (Java Build Path).

Secondly, when I clean the project, Eclipse automatically creates `.gitignore` file containing entry for the folder in question.

What causes this behavior, and how to let Eclipse to use this folder as a source folder as it should?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the **folder is** marked as ***Derived***:

**Right-click** the folder, choose ***Properties*** and in the ***Resource*** section **uncheck** the ***Derived*** checkbox:

[image]